# Android Studio Gradle use variables

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When updating my App I would like to store the versionCode and versionName in one place, as it is needed in the Gradle and is visible in the App.

Part of Gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "my.awesome.app"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 8
    versionName "1.8.0"
}
```

Part of strings.xml:

```
<string name="app_name">My Awesome App</string>
<string name="app_version_code">8</string>
<string name="app_version_name">v.1</string>
<string name="foo_version">8</string>
<string name="bar_version">.0</string>
<string name="version">Version</string>
```

I already use the strings.xml in the Manifest.xml:

```
android:versionCode="@string/app_version_code"
android:versionName="@string/app_version_name">
```

It seems silly to me to have this data in 2 places. How can I get the values from strings.xml into gradle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you do not need to specify `android:versionCode` and `android:versionName` in `AndroidManifest.xml` if you specify them in `build.gradle` (you do right?).

Second, the framework would generate a `BuildConfig.java` class for you, which contains all the info you need in the scope of this question. I assume you need to refer to those values for some reason:

[image]

So, you may refer to e.g. version code from anywhere through your code by

```
BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
```